# Slow HorizontalScrollView on big screens

Tags: android, performance, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I am creating an application with a `HorizontalScrollView`. This works fine on the device which I use for testing. But on bigger screens the application becomes very slow. 
I already tried to put `hardwareAccelerated` to "false" and this only gives a little more performance but still lags very badly.

I use images with the correct size, I tested this multiple times and tried smaller images as well. It looks like the problem starts with a screensize above 4.3 inch.

Is there a fix for this problem or is it better to use another type of scrollfunction?

Answer (score 0):

There are no known performance problems with scrolling HorizontalScrollViews. Your problem is likely related to the draw or layout operations of the layouts held within it.

You may want to use the Hierarchy Viewer to inspect the timings of those views to pinpoint your problem.

Comment: Thanks for this information, I will look if I can find a solution this way.